# Exclude similar values from awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, text

Kindly consider below files:

File 1:

```
boo,194,2322
foo,999,7559
```

File 2:

```
boo,2322
boo,4526
foo,4222
foo,4223
```

I need to link `Field1` in **File 1** with `Field1` in **File 2** and get the related `Field2` from **File 2**, while excluding the result if it's equal to `Field3` in **File 1**.

The result should be:

```
boo,4526
foo,4222,4223
```

I tried the below script, but it does not exclude the similar values.

```
awk -F, 'NF==3{arr[$1]=$3}{if(arr[$1]==$1){print $2}}'
```

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro your comment isn't helpful anyway!

Comment: You need to check whether `$1` is in `arr` and if so whether the value is different from `$2` and then print, don't you?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check whether `$1` is in `arr` and if so whether the value is different from `$2` and then print:

```
awk -F, 'FNR == NR { arr[$1] = $3; next }
         { if ($1 in arr && arr[$1] != $2) print $2 }'
```

Using `FNR == NR` and `next` is the conventional way to process lines in the first file differently from the lines in other files.  Yes, you can flatten it onto one line, but 'one-liner' is a pejorative term unless you're writing APL (or perhaps Perl).